# How to create rhythm parts on piano?

Tags: piano, rhythm, improvisation, accompaniment

I am trying to self learn piano. I can play some melody (right hand), can play some chords (left hand) and can play some melody with chords (right + left) with right doing all the complex finger movements for the melody and left just pressing the chord keys once at each change.

I am trying to play something more complex with left hand and interleave the notes with those on the right hand melody. But I do not know how to come-up with the rhythm parts. I try arpeggiating the chords instead of "playing" them but result does not fit in and sounds muddy. Also been trying a few other patterns for a while now, but nothing seems to stick.

My question: are there some patterns (rule of thumb etc.) for coming up with rhythm patterns given a melody? For example, in case of chords, one can rarely go wrong playing the chord for the root note of the melody and a progression thereof.

PS: Not sure if this is classified as "improvisation", but tagging it so.

Comment: Not an answer (as I don't have much more to add), but something like this: http://musingsofaministerswife.com/music-2/10-standard-left-hand-patterns-for-piano-explained/ might be worth a read.

Comment: @ James: good link. I've also found somthing: https://www.helblingchoral.com/media/catalog/products/S7965/doc/keyboard_acc.pdf and  https://s3.amazonaws.com/tjtassetdelivery/Left+Hand+Pattern+Worksheet+-+Freebie.pdf but there are lots of them Looking for piano patterns left hand:
http://keyboardimprov.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/PopBalladAccompaniment_Complete_Book.pdf

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Thanks for the links! Going to check them out in a bit. Note: it is not just about left hand patterns but how to "fuse" them with the melody that is where I am having the most trouble.

Comment: I learnt this just when I bought song arrangements with sometime bass and accompaniment in the left hand and others with bass left and melody and chords in the right hand. With the latter I struggled more but as you mean to say: for improvisation this is good to learn both. And you have it much easier today as you can just google and download ... ;)

Comment: I recently made a two-minute video to illustrate an answer on this site, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78-Ggxq6868 Is the rhythm aspect anything like what you mean? If so, I could try writing an answer and perhaps a more advanced video. The question for which I made the video is this one: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/79638/transitioning-from-arranger-keyboard-to-piano/79658

Answer (score 1):

I think 'improvisation' connotates for many people improvising a melody over chord changes like in jazz or a rock guitar solo. But, you are asking about improvising the rhythm part - the accompaniment part. You can try finding resources using keywords like 'accompaniment' or 'comping'. You can also look for guides along the lines of 'how to play from a lead sheet.' A lead sheet is just the song melody with chord names above the melody.

Here are two samples that seem good. Both show how *a simple pattern can be adapted through small variations*.

Jazz waltz using bass on beat 1, chord on beats 2 and 3...

[image]

- https://mascaripianostudios.com/music-theory/jazz-waltz/

A synopated rock rhythm...

[image]

- http://www.musicarta.com/beat-and-rhythm_6xx.html

The value of these kinds of resources will depend a lot of the style you want to play and the kind of learner you are. (For example, some people can't read notation and so notated sources aren't so helpful.) Look around for what fits your interest. Some items have previews online, but if not, you can try to get material through your library before committing to buy anything.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn to improvise was for me:

left hand: bass

right hand: chords

**and the melody: singing by my self!**

(or accompanying someone else)

so my hands were free for the rhythm and later able to  play the melody while the chords 
were added to the bass or to the tune in the right hand. This gave me the greatest flexibility and this is the basic of improvising.